# Server not powering on after upgraded to Intel Xeon E5-2695 v2

Tags: hardware, hp, xeon

Have a ProLiant DL360p Gen8. Old CPUs were E5-2670. Upgraded HP latest [ROM](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5194969&swItemId=MTX_cdac009824154b27b3b3637a69&swEnvOid=4184)

Server does not power on any more. See amber LED light on the CPU in the Systems Insight Display.

As far as I know this CPU is supported on this server. What am I missing?

Comment: Can power on after putting old CPUs back.

Comment: Have you updated all firmware using the SPP?

Comment: I downloaded SP99341.exe and followed the instructions

Comment: You need to get that special firmware to go to v2 CPUs on Gen8 servers - https://serverfault.com/a/774990/13325

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah I remembered this one, it'd dropped out of my memory sorry, just remembered. There was an extra step you need to do when going from v1 Xeons to v2's - HPE made a service advisory for it, you need to download the ISO file, put it on a USB stick and run it with the v1 Xeon's in it, only then will you be able to go to v2's - here's the link, it was a bit of a pain but it worked fine; https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c03911173

Comment: Sounds promising! Will test it out.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot about it, we had to do it to loads of BL460c's at the time, it was a few years ago and I"m getting old - I'm sure it'll sort out the problem